# MediaPlayer Issue in android

Tags: android, media-player

I am developing an app after the first Activity finished. I am starting music through `mediaplayer` and navigating through a number of activities in the last activity. I am not able to stop mediaplayer. I have called the first-activity class method to stop mediaplayer but it is showing nullpointer exception can any one provide me an relevant solution, I have not used a service class.

the below shown is the first activity where i am starting the mediaplayer.

```
public class GamemenuActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        Button newgame, highscore, help,sound;
        MediaPlayer mp;
        int i=0;
        TranslateAnimation anim, anim511, anim2511,animsound;
        BounceInterpolator bo;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.menuscreen);
            media();
            newgame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgamebutton);
            highscore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.highscoresButton);
            help = (Button) findViewById(R.id.helpbutton);
            sound=(Button)findViewById(R.id.soundbutton);
            anim = new TranslateAnimation(3250, 0, 100, 0);
            anim511 = new TranslateAnimation(3250, 0, 100, 0);
            anim2511 = new TranslateAnimation(3250, 0, 100, 0);
            animsound=new TranslateAnimation(3250, 0,100,0);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);

            newgame.startAnimation(anim);

            anim511.setDuration(3000);

            anim.setDuration(3000);
            anim511.setFillAfter(true);
            highscore.startAnimation(anim511);

            anim2511.setDuration(3000);
            anim2511.setFillAfter(true);
            help.startAnimation(anim2511);

            animsound.setDuration(3000);
            animsound.setFillAfter(true);
            sound.startAnimation(animsound);


            newgame.setOnClickListener(this);
            highscore.setOnClickListener(this);
            help.setOnClickListener(this);
            sound.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        public void media() {
             /* Intent i=new Intent(GamemenuActivity.this,Background.class);
              startService(i);*/

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.gameback);

            mp.start();
            mp.setVolume(1, 1);
            mp.setLooping(true);

        }

            public void stopmedia(){
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
           }
```

The activity where I want to end the music is below

```
public class Highpage extends Activity{
    TextView name,score;
    int sli;
    Button sub;
    Bundle base;
    SQLiteHelper sqdb;
    String data,val;
    GamemenuActivity gm; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            gm=new GamemenuActivity();
        TextView name=new TextView(this);
            TextView score=new TextView(this);
            base=getIntent().getExtras();
        data=base.getString("a");
        val=base.getString("b");
        sli=base.getInt("brk");
        name.setText(data);
        score.setText(val);
        System.out.println("values are"+data  +val);
        sqdb=new SQLiteHelper(this);
            sqdb.insertvalues(data, val,sli);
        Toast.makeText(Highpage.this, "values updated successfully", 30).show();

        //stopping media player
        gm.stopmedia();

        Intent hm=new Intent(Highpage.this,GamemenuActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        startActivity(hm);
        finish();
    }


}
```

This is the error in the logcat

```
12-23 14:54:37.179: E/AndroidRuntime(11970):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-23 14:54:37.179: E/AndroidRuntime(11970):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 14:54:37.179: E/AndroidRuntime(11970): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 14:54:37.179: E/AndroidRuntime(11970):    at mobbi.Stallion.imageteaser.GamemenuActivity.stopmedia(GamemenuActivity.java:80)
```

Comment: Release your mediaplayer after playing.

Comment: you are saying to do                                         mp.stop();                                                   mp.release();                                               i have done in the last activity where i have to stop mediaplayer but not working

Comment: see the code i have updated my question

Comment: Dude what have you done? Why are you creating an instance of `GameMenuActivity`? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: Did you finish the GameMenuActivity before moving to the next Activity?

Answer (score 0):

You've coded really strangely here.

You have to understand that creating an object of an activity is not the same as running an Activity.(through any method eg.an intent)

So when you created an object of `GameMenuActivity` it will only run the constructor of the Activity.

It will NOT run the `onCreate()` method.

Therefore there is no object of `MediaPlayer` to stop or release. Hence a null pointer exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that you are not using a service, but in your scenario, the best thing to do is to use a service because you are creating 2 different instances of mediaplayer. you are calling stop on a mediaplayer which has not been started thus getting null pointer. Put the mediaplayer in an service and it will let you stop it.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/UsingServicetoplaymediafile.htm

Also you may want to bind it, in which you might not want to forget this piece of code in your mainActivity.

```
private ServiceConnection mediaServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder binder) 
    {
        mp3Service = ((LocalBinder) binder).getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) 
    {
    }

};
```

You will able to mess around with the mediaplayer by doing the following:

mp3Service.stop();

Comment: i got solution for my problem

Comment: instead of creating media method in gamemenuactivity i have written mediaplayer in on create itself now it is working thanks for all your support